# How To Access HTML5 data-* Attributes With JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make this code: `<div data-alert="abc@abc.com">Connect me(click me to know my email)</div>` `<script> var dataalert = /*access the "data-alert" here*/;window.alert("dataalert");`, but I don't know how to access it with my javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the div using the tag selector and then use `getAttribute` method of js to get the value of `data-alert` attribute.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-alert"))
```

```html
<div data-alert="abc@abc.com">Connect me(click me to know my email)</div>
```

Comment: but i have other div

Comment: I didn't understand what you are telling.